# How do I hard stop an Azure role?

Tags: windows, debugging, deployment, azure, cloud

Here's my scenario: my Azure web role does a lot of work in `OnStart()` and produces a huge debug  trace that is uploaded to Blob Storage.

Now [`OnStart()` hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6661652/57428) for whatever reason and I look into Blob Storage and see that trace has not been updated for several minutes already. So I decide the role is beyond repair and I want to shut it down immediately so that I can update the role with another package and start it again.

The problem is when I hit "Stop" in the Management Portal it takes up to ten minutes to stop the role - I guess it tries to convince the role to stop gracefully and wait for several minutes.

Can I somehow make the role stop immediately without letting it stop gracefully?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if deleting the deployment (that's presumably what you're going to do after stopping it?) is faster, but I'm not sure. As far as I know, there's only one kind of "stop," so no, I don't think there's a way to force a faster stop.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look @ [Windows Azure Platform PowerShell Cmdlets](http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/)

It should give you at least the same functionality and probably more control over the actions. You could also request the current status as it is not always reflected immediately in the Silverlight portal.